# sos and return statement

Tags: java, ajax

```
sos.print("{success:true}");
sos.close();
```

1. What is sos?
2. Whay do we close sos?
3. Where does it print, in the console or somewhere.

Is it something like a return statement

return "{success:true}";

Can i also pass my ajax response like this

Update...  I have updated the entire code here.

```
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

          try {
            ServletOutputStream  sos = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
            response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String age = request.getParameter("age");
            String city = request.getParameter("city");
            String phone = request.getParameter("phone");

            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Age: " + age);
            System.out.println("City: " + city);
            System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);

            String query ="INSERT INTO CRUD_DATA VALUES('"+name+"',"+age+",'"+city+"',"+phone+")";
            System.out.println("Query:" + query);

            OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setUser("abdel");
            ods.setPassword("password");
            ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1/XE");

            Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            statement.executeUpdate(query);
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();           

            sos.print("{success:true}");
            sos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Only you can answer what `sos` is. You have the code in front of you - we don't. Basically, we haven't got any idea of what you're doing - you haven't given us any context. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: SOS what is sos? · · · — — — · · ·

Answer (score 2):

*What is sos?*
You should check the code you've taken it from and see how `sos` is defined. In Java, object behaviour is defined by its type and not name.

*Whay do we close sos?*
**shit, I've been reading it "why do we call it 'sos'" :)**
Probably, its class is `S***OutputStream`

*Where does it print, in the console or somewhere.*
Again, my guess is that it prints data into a buffer of `ServletResponse` object.

**edit**
So, this is the important line to understand what `sos` is

```
ServletOutputStream  sos = response.getOutputStream();
```

You can check documentation for [ServletOutputStream object](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html) and [getOutputStream method](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29).

*Can i also pass my ajax response like this*
Yes, you can pass response from your Java servlet to client's browser like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a [ServletOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html)
2. To release all system resources associated with this stream.
3. It is sent back to client in `response`